# Jenkins pipeline stages as to be done

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'd like to set up a Jenkins pipeline so that some of the later stages are to be done. What I mean is the first couple stages have been implemented but the latter stages have not. There is some business value for me and showing the future stages as

For example, build, unit test, and integration test stages are all implemented and run in order to determine the success of the build. But there could also be two follow on stages called create docker and deploy to cloud which are not done and would have no effect on the build.

Is this possible?

Comment: you mean you need a stage that has no action?

Comment: Yes but I'd also like it to not just look like it succeeded. A state of 'pending' or 'future'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`when`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) :

```
 when { expression { return false } }
```

This will skip and provide a ? visual (in BlueOcean) while retaining the placeholder.